# Creating multiple variables "name + i" in a for loop (JAVA)

Tags: java

Hey is there a way to create multiple variables in a for loop?
Here is an example of what i "want" my code to look like

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    int[] arr(i) = new int[i+1];
    for(int j=0; j<=i; j++) {
        arr(i)[j] = j+1;
    } //for
} //for
```

I want to create 10 arrays like this:

```
arr0: [1]
arr1: [1, 2]
arr2: [1, 2, 3]
arr3: etc
...
```

Comment: In Java you cannot make variable names at run-time like this.  You can use an `int [][]` in order to handle 2 dimensional arrays, or just use a `List` of `List`.

Comment: So that means i have to make 10 arrays by hand? Or is there a way of doing that smarter. How do i create for a example 1000arrays of name array1, array2, array3 without doing it by hand

Comment: No you just need to use loops to do it, if you ever are doing something like `array1` `array2`, by hand with numbers at the end, chances are you don't actually need to do it by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using a 2-D array as shown below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = new int[10][];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = new int[i + 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = j + 1;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("arr" + i + ": " + Arrays.toString(arr[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
arr0: [1]
arr1: [1, 2]
arr2: [1, 2, 3]
arr3: [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr4: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr6: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
arr7: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
arr8: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
arr9: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: I have one suggestion, I recommend using `i < arr.length` instead of `i < 10` for your outer loop and when printing, instead of hard coding `10` 3 times.  This will make it so when you change `new int [10]` to `100` it will work just fine and won't error out or require you to change the number elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create new variables like that.  You do have several options.

1. Used An array of arrays.  Sometimes referred to as 2-D arrays.

```
int[][] v = new int[4][6];
```

2. You can also use a map.

```
Map<String, int[]> arrays = new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arrays.put("arr" + i, new int[10]);
}
```

You can then access each array as a string.

```
arrays.get("arr1")[4] = 3;
```